# Android Studio + JSON getting values

Tags: java, php, json, android-studio, textview

I've been looking for this piece a really long time, but still can't find it.

I have solutions with `JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result)` but I can't use that one, getting an *Unhandled JSON Exception* there.

So, what I got:

```
[{"NAME":"test"},{"NAME":"John"}]
```

This JSON-bit can be expanded.

What I got in my code:
First I'm getting the data out of a .php form.

```
    public class Download extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String out = null;

        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            final HttpParams httpParameters = httpClient.getParams();

            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 15000);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 15000);

            HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            out = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity, HTTP.UTF_8);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return out;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        showJSON.setText(result);
        Log.e(TAG, result);
        jsonText = result;
    }
}
```

To show the code in the app, I use a Textview:

```
    private ArrayList<searchResults> GetSearchResults(){
    ArrayList<searchResults> results = new ArrayList<searchResults>();

    searchResults sr1 = new searchResults();
    sr1.setName("test"); //this should be jsonobj.getString("NAME")
    results.add(sr1);

    sr1 = new searchResults();
    sr1.setName("test1"); //This should be jsonobj.getString("NAME")
    results.add(sr1);


    return results;
}
```

Now: how do I get the *test* and *John* piece out of the array? And afterwards, as the json could be expanded, how do I make the view (private ArrayList getSearchResults) dynamic (automatically adding new rows for more values in the array)?

I hope this is somewhat readable. Feel free to edit!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To convert a JSON-String to an object, I would recommend to use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson).

To add Gson, add `compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'` to your build.gradle dependencies.

```
SearchResult[] data = new Gson().fromJson(out, SearchResult[].class);
```

would  convert your String to an Array of SearchResults.

However I don't know, what you mean with dynamically adding, please try to update your question, if the converting works.

Comment: By dynamically adding I meant that if there're more then 1 values, new searchReasults() (see last bit of code) will be added automatically. Or perhaps simplier: fill a table in Android Studio using JSON.

Comment: You can use textView.append() if you want add something to a TextView. Probably the thing you are looking for is a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html)

Comment: Ok, I get that part. But, if you check the code, the string is coming from the PostExecute (result). I guess I can do the same for that as you did with the SearchResult?

Comment: Yes, if you have trouble passing the object around you could use some sort of callback.